# Windows Phone 7 Looped Navigation 

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Let's say I have Four pages in my app. Assume that they are Acs.xaml, MainPage.xaml, Home.xaml, and Weather.xaml.( As I'm Using the Access Control Service (ACS) to perform the authentication functionality).

Now After Authentication ACS Redirect Me To MainPage.xml and MainPage.xaml has two buttons on it, one of which takes the user to Home while the other takes them to Weather.

Now, when I'm on Home, I want another button to take them to Weather. Similarly, when I'm on Weather, I want a button to take them Home.(In Both Home.xaml  And Weather.xaml I'am Using Charts,graphs using Data visualization toolkit[Silverlight)

I' Have Gone Through The windowsteamblog(Circular Navigation) But Nothing Is Working Fine...As I Reach MainPage.xaml And Click On Any of the Button I Get A Error Something Like Navigation Failed, I Also Tried Panorama But Not Able To Solve The Problem.

LoginPageCode:-

```
namespace PhoneApp1.Pages
{
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.Phone.Identity.AccessControl



public partial class LoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly SimpleWebTokenStore swtStore = Application.Current.Resources["swtStore"] as SimpleWebTokenStore;

    public LoginPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        this.PageTransitionReset.Begin();
        this.SignInControl.RequestSimpleWebTokenResponseCompleted +=
            (s, e) => 
            {
                // The ACS token was successfully received and stored in the "swtStore" application resource.
                // TODO: Navigate to your main page i.e.:
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            };
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New) && this.swtStore.IsValid())
        {
            // There is a valid ACS token already in the "swtStore" application resource.
            // TODO: Navigate to your main page i.e.:
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            // There is not a valid ACS token in the "swtStore" application resource.
            // The token may be expired or it is the first time the user logs in.
            this.PageTransitionIn.Begin();
            this.SignInControl.GetSimpleWebToken();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PageTransitionReset.Begin();
    }
}
```

}`

MainPage Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;


using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Chart
{

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{


// Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {




InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(@"/Home.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(@"/Weather.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
}`
```

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: @Ashutosh To prevent people from closing the question on you, I reworded it to the best of my understanding. If I missed your meaning, I'm sorry, and do go ahead and edit it again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you'd be better off using a [`Panorama` control](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Panorama_and_Pivot_Controls) allowing the user to cycle through the screens, rather than having them push buttons to go from one to the other.

If you're absolutely dead set on buttons, then when pressed, use the [`NavigationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.aspx) to reach another page.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Weather.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

To go back, they would intuitively press the Back button on their device, but again if you're dead set on providing a custom button, you can programmatically navigate backwards.

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're describing a non-linear navigation cycle - something that Microsoft realised might come up, after the release of the initial SDK, and released a recipe for it. You can find a blog post [Solving Circular Navigation in Windows Phone Silverlight Applications](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx) at the Windows Phone Team Blog. It links through to [Recipe: Non-Linear Navigation Service for Windows Phone 7](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7) which has sample code for you to download.